# How to add more columns in Outlook in MacOs?

Tags: macos, email, ms-office

On my MacBook Pro M1 2020 (macOS Monterey 12.4), I use Outlook, which has a completely different interface as the Windows version. In particular I'd like to add more columns like "to:" or "Importance" or "Size":

[image]

When I right-click in the header there are filter and sort options and I can go to settings. But the settings seem not to offer anything useful to my question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which option do you get if you right click on the column header ??

Comment: This is the "New Outlook" and nothing happens when you click the headers @ReneLarsen

Comment: @ReneLarsen I added screenshots of the right-click + settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the old functionality of the reader, you have to disable the New Outlook from the Outlook menu. It is not currently possible to accomplish this in the New Outlook v 16.63 (or in recent past versions of the app)

This closes the app and relaunches it with the old code base and old mail database profile structure and then you can choose your columns as expected.

[image: not new Outlook for Mac column choice]

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll stay with the older look until they provide that feature (and others!) in the new version.

Comment: Microsoft is threatening to move windows users to this new look. We shall see if they have the stomach to endure people like you that rightly expect this feature and make good use of it.